# Cannot run make - created executables

Tags: c, makefile, valgrind

I've written a simple program to run a towers of hanoi game (hanoi.c). The Makefile is very simple:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

all: hanoi

clean:
rm -f hanoi
```

I call `make` and it produces an executable `hanoi`, but when I try to run `./hanoi` I only get the following output:

```
bash: ./hanoi: No such file or directory
```

And when I run with valgrind it says:

```
 valgrind: m_ume.c: can't open interpreter
```

Any ideas why this might be? I was running other simple C programs earlier with no such trouble and don't know of any changes that should have affected gcc or make... I am running Ubuntu 11.10. Thanks!

Comment: I still haven't figured out why the make executables aren't working, but the work-around I'm usign for now is to just call `gcc ./infile.c -o outfile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this myself.  Both of these errors arise when a dynamically-linked application is pointing to a dynamic loader that doesn't exist.

If your dynamic loader is `/lib64/ld.so.1` (for example), you should be able to run the application as:

```
/lib64/ld.so.1 ./hanoi
```

and run it under Valgrind as

```
valgrind /lib64/ld.so.1 ./hanoi
```

To determine what dynamic loader the program is expecting, you can use `readelf -l ./hanoi`.  The output should include a line in the middle like:

```
[Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld.so.1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you on the `fat/vfat` partition of your hard-disk ?
if you can see hanoi (executable) file in the cwd, then check whether it is executable using `ls -all`, there should be `x`. Also check the output of `file hanoi`, it should say similar to

```
hanoi: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped
```

Answer (score 1):

If that's your entire makefile, I see no rule with which to make `hanoi`.  You may be interested in something like this.

```
hanoi: hanoi.c
    gcc CFLAGS -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Useful, but the given makefile **can** produce the executable named hanoi, using GNU make, and the question specifies that make _produces an executable `hanoi`_.

Comment: This is not necessary in case of using GNU Make, because it infers the build chain by using its [built-in implicit rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules). Moreover, one can produce an executable even without any Makefile, just by running `make CFLAGS="-Wall -g" hanoi`.